# Increment the value of text in expandable listview

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have created the custom Expandablelistview.That list view contains plus and minus image view and one text view in child items.If i click the plus in one row means it increase the value increased as 1. But if i move on to the next row the value increment gets started from 2. I want to increase the value from 0 for each child items.

```
 public class ExpandListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Group> groups;
    ArrayList<Child> ch_list=new ArrayList<Child>();
    private ViewHolder viewHolder; // make it global
    private int count=0;
    int[] myIntegerArray = new int[10100];

    public class ViewHolder {

        TextView tv ;
        ImageView food_image;
        ImageView minus,plus ;
        TextView item_count;

    }


    public ExpandListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Group> groups) {
        this.context = context;
        this.groups = groups;

    }


    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        ArrayList<Child> chList = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();
        return chList.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final Child child = (Child) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.detail_list, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.type);
            viewHolder.food_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.food_image);
            viewHolder.minus = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.minus);
            viewHolder.plus = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.plus);
            viewHolder.item_count = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.count);


            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.tv.setText(child.getChildName());
        viewHolder.item_count.setText(child.getCount());
        viewHolder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Child modelChild = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems().get(childPosition);
                count = count + 1;
                modelChild.setCount(count);
                modelChild.setChildName(modelChild.getChildName());
                // set your other items if any like above
                groups.get(groupPosition).getItems().set(childPosition, child);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        viewHolder.minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(count!=0) {
                    Child modelChild = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems().get(childPosition);
                    count = count - 1;
                    modelChild.setCount(count);
                    modelChild.setChildName(modelChild.getChildName());
                    // set your other items if any like above
                    groups.get(groupPosition).getItems().set(childPosition, child);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public  int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        ArrayList<Child> chList = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();
        return chList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Group group = (Group) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.group_item, null);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.group_name);
        tv.setText(group.getName());
        ExpandableListView eLV = (ExpandableListView) parent;
        int count = getGroupCount();
        if(count<1){

            eLV.expandGroup(groupPosition);
            // eLV.setGroupIndicator(null);
        }


        return convertView;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Child model:

```
public class Child {

    private String Name;
    private int Image,count;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return Image;
    }

    public void setImage(int Image) {
        this.Image = Image;
    }

    public void setcount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public int getcount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Group model:

```
    public class Group {

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Child> Items;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ArrayList<Child> getItems() {
        return Items;
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<Child> Items) {
        this.Items = Items;
    }



}
```

Logcat error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: abservetech.com.foodapp, PID: 14471
                                                                     android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x0
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.getResourcePackageName(Resources.java:1871)
                                                                         at android.content.res.SPRDResources.getThemeResources(SPRDResources.java:94)
                                                                         at android.content.res.SPRDResources.getText(SPRDResources.java:155)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getText(ResourcesWrapper.java:52)
                                                                         at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3927)
                                                                         at abservetech.com.foodapp.ExpandListAdapter.getChildView(ExpandListAdapter.java:83)
                                                                         at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:451)
                                                                         at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2280)
                                                                         at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1271)
                                                                         at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1183)
                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16512)
```

[image]

Comment: whats the issue its not increment  properly?

Comment: Initially the count value is 0 for all child item.If i click the plus in 1st row,the count value increased from 0 to 1.After that,i clicked  the 2nd row means the count value increased from 1 to 2.I want to increase the count value as 0 to 1 in not 1 to 2 in 2nd row

Comment: You can do it by POJO class value not static count you use now

Comment: could you explain me clearly

Comment: like take one int variable in Group model class and increment it for each position by 1

Comment: its like getter setter method am i right

Comment: yes its like getter setter

Comment: i have tried using getter setter.But it show nothing value count not increment it remains as 0.I have posted my edited code @Nisarg

Comment: where you adding child value can you tell me ?

Comment: inside the  viewHolder.plus.setOnClickListener i.e(ch_list.add(ch);)

Comment: that one is correct r not

Comment: you have to take one global arraylist of child ,use it everywhere when needed and whenever you make changes in it notify it

Comment: till now no action happens can u explain with simple code

Comment: i have post my updated code

Comment: wait i'll post what I am trying to say

Comment: can you show me your screen ? I am lil confused

Comment: i have shared my screen @Nisarg

Comment: I have tried in demo its changing let me share with you and undone the changes of arraylist of child I told you to make and post your child model so that i can edit

Comment: now i have updated @Nisarg

Comment: check my answer and let me know if it still causes issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116377/discussion-between-nisarg-and-abserve-tech).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private ViewHolder viewHolder; // make it global

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Child child = (Child) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.detail_list, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.type);
        viewHolder.food_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.food_image);
        viewHolder.minus = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.minus);
        viewHolder.plus = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.plus);
        viewHolder.item_count = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.count);


        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.childName.setText(child.getChildName());
    viewHolder.item_count.setText(child.getCount());
    viewHolder.ivPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                Child modelChild = groups.get(groupPosition).getChildrens().get(childPosition);

                if(modelChild.getCount()>=0)  // set your count default 0 when you bind data initially 
                int count = modelChild.getCount() + 1;

                modelChild.setCount(count);
                modelChild.setChildName(modelChild.getChildName());
                // set your other items if any like above
                groups.get(groupPosition).getChildrens().set(childPosition, child);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    viewHolder.ivMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(count!=0) {
                Child modelChild = groups.get(groupPosition).getChildrens().get(childPosition);

                if(modelChild.getCount()>0)  // set your count default 0 when you bind data initially 
                int count = modelChild.getCount() - 1;

                modelChild.setCount(count);
                modelChild.setChildName(modelChild.getChildName());
                // set your other items if any like above
                groups.get(groupPosition).getChildrens().set(childPosition, child);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: can u explain this line "Child modelChild = groups.get(groupPosition).getChildrens().get(childPosition);"

Comment: @Abserve Tech its fetching your child item of particular position where you click and did it work ?

Comment: no it got error 
 Process: abservetech.com.foodapp, PID: 24040android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x0 at android.content.res.Resources.getResourcePackageName(Resources.java:1871)

Comment: if i use your code as it us means the error shown in getChildren() place

Comment: @AbserveTech what it suggesting to take ?

Comment: it suggest to take as directory in group model.what to do for that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116379/discussion-between-nisarg-and-abserve-tech).

Comment: @AbserveTech  change   groups.get(groupPosition).getItems().set(childPosition, child); to    groups.get(groupPosition).getItems().set(childPosition, modelChild);

Comment: if i do like this means no changes happen.If i click the plus in 1 st row means it increases the value as 1. after that,if i move on to the next row the value increment gets started from 2.

Comment: @AbserveTech dont take your count global than and finally it notifies :)

Comment: @AbserveTech Welcome :) Glad I could help you.